# How to do animation using xml files in android?

Tags: android, animation

I am a new developer to android, I want to do some animation using XML files.

```
I have category for animation :
1. Rotate 2. Scale 3. Traslate 4. Fade 5. page curl.
```

Out of this I have done the first four. Only the page curl animation remains for me to do, but I have no idea regarding this animation. Does someone have an idea for it ?

Comment: Try this - http://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/

Comment: here is the example for Page curl... https://github.com/harism/android_page_curl

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on achieving what you have so far!

I don't believe that Android has an already available page curl feature but you can clone one of the libraries from this list and reuse other peoples' code!

https://github.com/search?q=android+page+curl&ref=cmdform